# finding density of points along a line to find the region that has maximum concentration

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping, distribution

Finding point with dense neighbourhood

I have a set (count=485) of values in range 0.015 to 0.13 with six digit precision.

I want to use numpy in python .

I have tried

```
b = []
with open('data.txt') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for n in line.split()[2:3]:
            b.append(n)
xa = np.asarray(b,dtype=float)
print 'mode-',stats.mode(xa)
```

Here data.txt has values in third column.
This gives value that appears multiple times .
In my case 0.06 appeared twice.
So, above code does not work for my case.

Can there be a graph using which it can be interpreted that point x has densest neighbourhood if there is a peak at 'x' .

I am not able to define 'neigbourhood' . You can decide by yourself .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` to plot a histogram that will show you a peak. You can also use `np.histogram()` which will return identical results. Edit: I have used `np.argmax()` here now on the histogram frequency results to find our largest window. Have also plotted a line on the histogram to show heighest frequency.

You can also check out `numpy.genfromtxt()` or `pandas.read_csv()` for easy opening of files.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#Synthetic Data
dat=np.random.uniform(0.015,0.13,485)#(count=485) of values in range 0.015 to 0.13

binsize=20 #number of windows you want
hist=plt.hist(dat,bins=binsize) #Plot and get our histogram values
#hist=np.histogram(dat,bins=binsize) #will also work, just not plot the answer.

#hist[0] is frequencies and hist[1] is x value

ans=hist[1][np.argmax(hist[0])]
print('Answer: '+str(ans))

buffer=(hist[1][2]-hist[1][1])/2 #Just to centre the black line
plt.axvline(ans+buffer,c='k') #Draw a line of centre
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are not really answering OP's question here. I think he wants to find large clusters of values in the histogram rather than a single highest count value

Comment: This divided range of values into 20 bins and assigns each value to a bin then makes a histogram of it .
I upvoted it but my question is more about finding biggest cluster as MaximGi said .

Comment: Histograms are a basic density estimation. You can tune this depending on how big you make the bin window. For a kernel density approach you can check out https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_kde_1d.html `sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity ` but I am not familiar with this function.